# Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: Instance of 'Encrypted'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, encryption, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add encryption to my chat application . but facing an issue while doing so , i cant
add the data to firebase , it shows an error `Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: Instance of 'Encrypted'`. how can i send a message that is encrypted from client side and send it to firebase and then receive the message , then decrypt it . because i am using the library encrypt 5.0.0 for this and to decrypt it , it only accept the `Encrypted` as  parameter .

here is class for encryption and decryption .

```
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart' as encrypt;
class MyEncryptionDecryption{

  ///for encrption

 static final key = encrypt.Key.fromLength(32);
 static final iv = encrypt.IV.fromLength(16);
 static final  encrypter = encrypt.Encrypter(encrypt.AES(key));


  static encryptAES(message ){

   final encrypted =  encrypter.encrypt(message ,iv: iv);
      print(encrypted.base16);
      print(encrypted.base64);
      return encrypted;
  }
  static decryptedAES(message){

    return   encrypter.decrypt(message,iv: iv);

  }
  
}
```

using it to send message to firebase as this ..

```
var aes = MyEncryptionDecryption.encryptAES(message);
      Map<String, dynamic> messageInfoMap = {
        "message": aes,
        "sendBy": myUserName,
        "ts": lastMessageTs,
        "imgUrl": myProfilePic
      };


      DatabaseMethods()
          .addMessage(chatRoomId, messageId, messageInfoMap)
          .then((value) {


        Map<String, dynamic> lastMessageInfoMap = {
          "lastMessage": aes,
          "lastMessageSendTs": lastMessageTs,
          "lastMessageSendBy": myUserName,
          "readStatus" : false ,
          "count" : count,
          "show" : true,
        };

        DatabaseMethods().updateLastMessageSend(chatRoomId, lastMessageInfoMap);
```

and here are the Database functions ..

```
Future addMessage(String chatRoomId , String messageId,messageInfoMap) async {
   return await FirebaseFirestore.instance.
   collection("chatrooms").
   doc(chatRoomId).collection('chats').doc(messageId).set(messageInfoMap);
 }
 updateLastMessageSend(String chatRoomId, lastMessageInfoMap){
   return FirebaseFirestore
       .instance.collection('chatrooms').doc(chatRoomId)
       .update(lastMessageInfoMap);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Encrypted` is an object. You can retrieve actual value using [the fields defined in the API of `Encrypted`](https://pub.dev/documentation/encrypt/latest/encrypt/Encrypted-class.html), e.g. the property `bytes` to get the byte representation of the object or `base64` if you require the ciphertext as text.

Of course, you can revert back to `Encrypted` using one of the constructors: just the `Encrypted` constructor for bytes or `fromBase64` for text.

Comment: Although this is pretty basic stuff, I have answered because the examples for the `encrypt` functionality all seem to lack the required encoding / decoding of the `Encrypted` ciphertext representation, and I agree that could easily wrong-foot developers.